# changing /client/BigBlueButton.html portion getting:404 Not Found nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu

Tags: bigbluebutton

trying to when change  /client/BigBlueButton.html portion of the URL according to - http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/support/faq.html#how-do-i-change-the-client-bigbluebutton-html-portion-of-the-url,

but getting -

```
    404 Not Found

nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

my /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/client.nginx:

```
#location /client/BigBlueButton.html {
#    root /home/firstuser/dev/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-client;
#    index index.html index.htm;
#    expires 1m;
#}

# BigBlueButton Flash client.
location /client {
root /home/firstuser/dev/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-client;
index index.html index.htm;
}
```

my /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/rewrite.nginx:

```
location /client/BigBlueButton.html {
    rewrite ^ /conference permanent;
}

location /conference {
    alias  /var/www/bigbluebutton/client;
    index BigBlueButton.html;
    expires 1m;
}
```

$sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart

/var/log/nginx/bigbluebutton.access.log

```
    33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:37:57 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2852 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:37:57 -0400] "GET /css/bijou.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2753 "http://M_IP_Ad/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:37:57 -0400] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2918 "http://M_IP_Ad/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:37:57 -0400] "GET /css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 20766 "http://M_IP_Ad/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:37:57 -0400] "GET /images/jimtalk-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 10251 "http://M_IP_Ad/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:37:57 -0400] "GET /images/bbb-setup-audio.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 18876 "http://M_IP_Ad/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:37:57 -0400] "GET /images/bbb-viewer-overview.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 21929 "http://M_IP_Ad/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:37:57 -0400] "GET /images/bbb-presenter-overview.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 18309 "http://M_IP_Ad/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:37:58 -0400] "GET /fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 83760 "http://M_IP_Ad/css/font-awesome.min.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
M_IP_Ad - - [16/Aug/2015:12:38:00 -0400] "POST /bigbluebutton/api/create?name=Demo+Meeting&meetingID=Demo+Meeting&voiceBridge=72274&attendeePW=ap&moderatorPW=mp&record=false&checksum=a93ab8433532c633ab2467afc0d91e0eb1dc4e88 HTTP/1.1" 200 488 "-" "Java/1.7.0_79"
33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:38:00 -0400] "GET /demo/demo1.jsp?username=%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99&action=create HTTP/1.1" 200 1003 "http://M_IP_Ad/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:38:01 -0400] "GET /bigbluebutton/api/join?meetingID=Demo+Meeting&fullName=%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99&password=mp&checksum=3438ed39a50723be59798038f86fcba0af30b325 HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "http://M_IP_Ad/demo/demo1.jsp?username=%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99&action=create" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:38:02 -0400] "GET /client/BigBlueButton.html HTTP/1.1" 301 193 "http://M_IP_Ad/demo/demo1.jsp?username=%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99&action=create" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:38:02 -0400] "GET /conference HTTP/1.1" 301 193 "http://M_IP_Ad/demo/demo1.jsp?username=%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99&action=create" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
33.126.263.65 - - [16/Aug/2015:12:38:02 -0400] "GET /conference/ HTTP/1.1" 403 208 "http://M_IP_Ad/demo/demo1.jsp?username=%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%99&action=create" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The nginx read all the files with nginx extension (*.nginx). I guess the problem is that nginx is not able to handle same locations.